# adding small container into the big container,if in big containers one floor are 2 small containers (see pictures)

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

[image]

i want that user can write text in container "your text" then press add. Then there will get created new container with users provided information in the big container (red line). i can do that,but what if i want that there are 2 posts in one floor?

If there is floor with 2 posts and user adds new  one, the full floor moves down and new post comes in and is in the left side in the newest floor. then if the user adds another one it will be put in the newest floors right side. That is the logic. And so on.

I dont need complete code , maybe some tutorial or JUST IDEA how to do this,because i can
add just 1 post and then in 1 floor would be 1 post,something similar to 'TODO' app.
But what to do if i want 2 things in 1 floor?
Maybe there is some jquery plugin?

**as requested,here are pictures how it should happen**

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Thanks !

Comment: can you post separate images that is image for each step mentioned in 2nd paragraph of the question this will help to get a clear picture of the problem from the start to end

Comment: yes,i added the pictures

Comment: are you doing this in angular ?

Comment: i can do it in angular or jquery,i will watch your ideas,then i will check which technology is the best for that idea

Comment: are you familiar with angular? If not would not suggest making decision to use based on this fairly simple module.

Comment: idea in `mulquin's` answer is almost same as what I was thinking so have you tried to transform his idea into code? if you are finding it difficult or encountering some problem to transform his idea into code let me know I will see what i can do to help you

Comment: thanks guys ! i will try to write code,mulqin's idea is good,i will try that,if i will have problems will ask!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as you have not mentioned what your website or application looks like and what it do so  what i think is not exactly same as what you are trying to achieve. If your motive is to just populate the container, that empty space in the first row does not looks great (as a view point of end-user). If I am using such UI then I shall expect something like this:-

```
                 _____
text1           [_____]
                  add
```

.

```
                 _______
text2 | text1   [_______]
                  add
```

.

```
                 _______
text3 | text2   [_______]     
------|------     add
text1 |
```

.

```
                 ______
text4 | text3   [______]
------|------     add
text2 | text1
```

Here is something that i have created. I hope this will make sense about what I am trying to say

[**FULL SCREEN DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/UD_B/5pJsG/3/embedded/result/)

[**CODE**](http://jsfiddle.net/UD_B/5pJsG/3/)

above demo supports:

**1.** removing a box from the container,

**2.** aloting `id` to the boxes on removing and adding a box as per their order in the container for example recently added box will have id `box1`

try to play with consecutive numbers `(1,2,3..)` or week days `(sunday,monday..)` etc

**NOTE:-** i have tested the code in `opera` and `chrome` only.Script used is not that much complicated as it looks but `css` contains some parts that are necessary if you want to follow the same html structure these parts have comments with (below) them

Answer (score 2):

Each floor could be a pair of `<div>`'s sitting in a `<li>` inside the larger red `<ul>`.

You would need to create a variable that acts as a "pointer", this pointer determines the floor level and position in the floor:

`floor: 0, position: [0,1]` (0 meaning floor is empty, 1 meaning floor is half filled)

A new `<li>` can be inserted when the floor increments, and `<div>`s can be added when position is either 0 or 1.

When position is greater than one, go down a level.

I hope this makes sense!

Comment: it doesnt matter that i marked this as answered,you can still give ideas!

Answer (score 1):

Can do this with jQuery using `prepend()` to add a new row if the top row is full, and adding text to 2nd item if it isn't.

HTML

```
<div style="padding:30px"><input/><button>Add</button></div>
<div id="content"> </div>
```

JS

```
/* second item in new row has empty class, used to determine if need to add row or not */
function newRow(txt){
   var row='<div class="row">';
    row+='<div class="item"><div class="item_text">'+txt+'</div></div>';
    row+='<div class="item"><div class="item_text empty">&nbsp;</div></div>'; 
    row+='<div style="clear:both"></div></div>';
 return row
}

$('button').click(function(){
    var txt=$('input').val(), $cont=$('#content');
    if( txt=='') return;
    var $emptyItem=$cont.find('.row:first .empty')
    if($emptyItem.length){
      $emptyItem.text(txt).removeClass('empty');  
    }else{
       $cont.prepend( newRow(txt) ); 
    }   

})
```

<kbd>**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Zt4W3/2/)**</kbd>